# How can I make vue-awesome-swiper loop normally and display the pagination?

Tags: vue.js, swiper.js

Recently,I used [vue-awesome-swiper](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-awesome-swiper) in my project.Here are my codes from the HomeSwiper.vue file:

```html
//HTML

<template>
  <swiper :options="swiperOption"  ref="mySwiper">  
      <swiper-slide v-for="(item,index) in banners" :key="index">  
        <a :href="item.link">
          <img :src="item.image" alt=""> 
        </a>  
      </swiper-slide>  
      <div class="swiper-pagination" v-for="(item,index) in  banners" :key="index" slot="pagination">
      </div>  
  </swiper>  
</template>
```

```js
// JS
import {swiper,swiperSlide} from 'vue-awesome-swiper'
require("swiper/dist/css/swiper.css");

export default {
  name:'HomeSwiper',
  props:{
    banners:{
      type:Array,
      default(){
        return []
      }  
    }
  },
  components:{
    swiper,
    swiperSlide
  },
  data() {  
    const that = this
    return {
      imgIndex: 1,
      swiperOption: {
        notNextTick: true,
        loop: true,
        initialSlide: 0,
        autoplay: {
          delay: 1500,
          stopOnLastSlide: false,
          disableOnInteraction: true
        },
        speed: 800,
        direction: "horizontal",
        grabCursor: true,
        on: {
          slideChangeTransitionStart: function() {
            that.imgIndex= this.realIndex - 1;
          },
        },
        pagination: {
          el: ".swiper-pagination",
          clickable: true,
          type: "bullets"
        }
      }
   }
  },   
  computed: {  
      swiper() {  
        return this.$refs.mySwiper.swiper;  
      }  
  }
}
```

The code snippet looks normally.But I met 2 strange problems:

1. I found the images can't loop normally,which always stop when reached the last image even though I have set loop to true in the script.
2. The pagination can't display

So I went to github issues for help.And Somenone who met the same problems solve these by using `v-if="banners.length!=0"` in swiper element.But I am confused why these 2 problems are something to do with banners'length?Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are missing the `<v-content>` tag from your view.

Your entire view should be wrapped with a `<v-content>` to ensure proper sizing. You can see the documentation here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/

**Template:**

```
<template>
    <v-content>
        <Swiper :options="swiperOption">
            <Swiper-Slide v-for="(item,index) in srcs" :key="index">
                <img class="slideImage" :src="require(`@/static/vuetifypro-pages/${ item }`)" :key="index" alt="">
            </Swiper-Slide>
            <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-white" slot="pagination"></div>
        </Swiper>
    </v-content>
</template>
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
    import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'vue-awesome-swiper';
    export default {
        name:'HomeSwiper',
        components:{
            Swiper,
            SwiperSlide
        },
        data() {
            return {
                srcs: {
                    1: 'Homepage_blur.jpg',
                    2: 'Login_bg.jpg',
                    3: 'home_huddle.jpg',
                },
                swiperOption: {
                    notNextTick: true,
                    loop: true,
                    initialSlide: 0,
                    autoplay: {
                        delay: 1500,
                        disableOnInteraction: true
                    },
                    speed: 800,
                    grabCursor: true,
                    pagination: {
                        el: ".swiper-pagination",
                        clickable: true,
                        type: "bullets"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with  Vuetify.It is just vue

Comment: I recreated your slider with codesandbox and it works 100%. Take a look here: https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-tdd-nxcdf?file=/swiperView.vue

I recommend double checking your vue-awesome-swiper dependencie with this example.

I tried to use your CSS import and the sandbox was not happy with it, hence the change. Perhaps this was what was causing your pagination to disappear. Hope this helps.